# Flutter path_provider and sdk version mismatch

Tags: flutter, dart

The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.5.

Because path_provider 2.0.1 requires SDK version >=2.12.0-259.9.beta <3.0.0 and no versions of path_provider match >2.0.1 <3.0.0, path_provider ^2.0.1 is forbidden.
So, because harmonoid depends on path_provider ^2.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because harmonoid depends on path_provider ^2.0.1, version solving failed.)

How do i solved this error? this is my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  animations: ^1.1.2
  provider: ^4.3.3
  assets_audio_player:
    git: https://github.com/alexmercerind/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer
  media_metadata_retriever: ^0.0.2+1
  http: ^0.12.2
  path: ^1.7.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^3.0.3
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  share: ^0.6.5+4
  palette_generator: ^0.2.3
  implicitly_animated_reorderable_list: ^0.3.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening your IDE; Android studio?

Comment: yes, and i tried also restart my laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Dart SDK version is 2.12.0, and the Flutter version is 2.0.1. I created a new project and copied all your dependencies. The project worked without any problems.

For saving your time, I recommend upgrading to the stable channel and [Flutter 2](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-0-fe8e95ecc65) using these commands or this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading).

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: so my problem is my dart version?

Comment: @Rene Probably the latest version of path_provider depends on new features of Dart SDK and Flutter framework. Also, there are lots of good feedbacks about Flutter 2 that you can find more about it in the Flutter engage event.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to migrate your Flutter and Dard SDK versions yet,

I would recommend you to try and remove the version from the line:

- `path_provider: ^2.0.1`
  so it would look like this: `path_provider:`
- run: `pub get` again
- run your project again

Eventually I would recomment to migrate to the newest version of the SDKs and upgrade all your dependencies. This is just a temporary solution.